# How can I take the last value -1 pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do a function where I check if a date is in my excel file, and if unfortunately it is not. I retrieve the date before.

I succeeded with the after date and here is my code.
Only with the date before, I really can't do it.

i tried this for the day before:

```
def get_all_dates_between_2_dates_with_special_begin_substraction(Class, date_départ, date_de_fin, date_debut_analyse, exclus=False):
    date_depart = date_départ
    date_fin = date_de_fin
    
    result_dates = []
    inFile = "database/Calendar_US_Target.xlsx"
    inSheetName = "Sheet1"
    df =(pd.read_excel(inFile, sheet_name = inSheetName))

    date_depart = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_depart, '%Y-%m-%d')
    date_fin = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_fin, '%Y-%m-%d')
    date_calcul_depart = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_debut_analyse, '%Y-%m-%d')

    var_date_depart = date_depart

    time_to_add = ""

    if (Class.F0 == "mois"):
        time_to_add = relativedelta(months=1)    
        
    if (Class.F0 == "trimestre"):
        time_to_add = relativedelta(months=3)    

    if (Class.F0 == "semestre"):
        time_to_add = relativedelta(months=6)    

    if (Class.F0 == "année"):
        time_to_add = relativedelta(years=1)    


    while var_date_depart <= date_fin:
-------------------------------------------------------------
        df['mask'] = (var_date_depart <= df['TARGETirs_holi']) # daybefore
        print(df.head())
        print(df[df.mask =="True"].head(1)) #want to check the last true value
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        if (result >= date_calcul_depart):
            result = (str(result)[0:10])
            result = result[8:10] + "/" + result[5:7] + "/" + result[0:4]
            result_dates.append(str(result))

        
        var_date_depart = var_date_depart + time_to_add
    
    if (exclus == True):
        result_dates = result_dates[1:-1]
    return(result_dates)
```

I want to say, do a column (or a dataframe) where the first date is true where the first date smaller than the second then i take the last value who is true.

for example:
I have this array [12-05-2022,15-05-2022,16-05-2022 and 19-05-2022]

if i put 15-05-2022, it gives me 15-05-2022, but if i put 18-05-2022, its gives me 16-05-2022

Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected output? and the variable result is used before assigning

Comment: i get this: line 133, in get_all_dates_between_2_dates_with_special_begin_substraction
  File "C:\Users\Guigui\Documents\Code\Python Scripts\equitim-back\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3505, in __getitem__     
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\Guigui\Documents\Code\Python Scripts\equitim-back\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3623, in get_loc  
    raise KeyError(key) from err

Comment: and yes i know for result, i just have to remplace my print by my result

Comment: What is your expected output? all the dates between date_fin and date_depart?

Comment: I want to have the earliest date (with substraction). For example i want to get the 19/02/2022 but its not in my dataframe, it will take the 16/02/2022 (who is my dataframe) and not the 20/02/2022 cause 16/02/2022 is the nearest date